# Which file extensions I should consider for file uploading on website?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am developing a site that needs image/audio files to be uploaded. Which file extensions I should check for other than JPG, PNG, GIF, and MP3?

Comment: It depends on what you want to allow and what your server can handle. These are probably the most common ones but there are a lot more out there: webp, tif, wav, flac, aac, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In general I would not trust users to be honest about the file extension. It is very easy to spoof and upload a script or malware, and depending on how you use these files after uploading that can be a security issue.

I recommend you use [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) to detect what file you are dealing with, or a library which does the same. The important difference is that we use the file data itself to figure out what it is. This works because most file types have a very recognizable signature.